# How many cores do I have in my machine?

Tags: ubuntu, make, core

I want to install a relatively huge package on my Ubuntu 13.10 and I want to use all of the processing cores of my machine. I type

> make -j N

where `N` is the number of available cores+1, I guess. But the problem is that I don't know how many cores do I have. How can I figure it out in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run `make -j` without any number then it will run as many as it can without limiting to the number you provide.

[Linux make man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gmake)

Answer (score 7):

Run `lscpu` to get information about your cpu.`nproc` returns the amount of processors

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your terminal :

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

@BuysDB definitely has the simplest solution that directly answers the question, but here's another, more cross-platform way to do it assuming python is installed:

### python 2

```
python -c 'import multiprocessing as mp; print mp.cpu_count()'
```

### python 3

```
python -c 'import multiprocessing as mp; print(mp.cpu_count())'
```